# How do I finalize my Docker setup and how is it actually called?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I am pretty new to Docker. After reading specifically what I needed I figured out how to create a pretty nice Docker setup. I have created some setup where in I can start up multiple systems using one docker-compose.yml file.

I am currently using this for testing specific PHP code on different PHP and MySQL versions. The file structure looks something like this:

- ./mysql55/Dockerfile
- ./mysql56/Dockerfile
- ./mysql57/Dockerfile
- ./php53/Dockerfile
- ./php54/Dockerfile
- ./php56/Dockerfile
- ./php70/Dockerfile
- ./php71/Dockerfile
- ./php72/Dockerfile
- ./web *(shared folder with test files available on all php machines)*
- ./master_web *(web interface to send test request to all possible versions using one call)*
- ./docker-compose.yml

In the docker-compose file I setup different containers most refering to the local Dockerfiles, some refering to online image names. When I run `docker-compose up` all containers start as expected in the configured network configuration and I'm able to use it as desired.

I would first of all like to know how this setup is called. Is this called a "docker swarn" or is such setup called differently?

Secondly, I'd like to make one "compiled/combined" file (image, container, swarn, engine, machine) or however it is called) of this. That I can save without having to depend on external sources again. Of course the docker-compose.yml file will work as long as all the refered external sources are still available. But I'd like to pusblish my fully confired setup as is. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can publish built images with [Docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/). You can setup your own or use third-party service.
After that, you need to prefix you image names with your registry IP/DNS in docker-compose.yml. This way, you can deploy it anywhere docker-compose is installed (and docker-compose itself can be run as docker container too), just need to copy your docker-compose.yml file there.
docker-machine is tool to deploy to multiple machines, as is [docker swar**m**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm/).